# jQuery - Scrolling to a location calculated by a var

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have the following script:

```
$('.how-we-do-it .items div').on('click', function () {
    var $matchingDIV = $('.how-we-do-it .sections .section .content div.' + $(this).attr('class'));
    $matchingDIV.toggle('fast');
});
```

I have been trying to add in some additional code so that the page automatically scrolls down to the $matchingDIV that gets toggled.

I have been trying to use scrollTop and also the Smooth Scroll plugin to accomplish this, but I cannot get it to work with my $matchingDIV output.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try animating the `scrollTop` property of the `html` and `body`:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $matchingDIV.offset().top }, delay);
```